# angularjs upload file with a single upload button

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I would like to know how can I upload files using angularjs without using external library and just a single upload button?
I have searched for the solution for a while and found a solution is pretty close to what I want as below:

```
<div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/

However, I want only a upload button and in the above case, how can I trigger uploadFile()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/7080/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller = "myCtrl">    
    <button>
    <input type="file" class="input" id="myfile" file-model="myFile"><a href="">Upload Me</a>
    </button>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#myfile {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

So that now when you click on "Upload Me" you will get the file explorer.

**Update**

Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/7081/

Comment: I am new to angularjs. I would like to know what the below two lines mean? Thanks!      document.getElementById("test").classList.remove("open");
                  <!--   scope.uploadFile(); -->

Comment: I am sorry here is the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/7081/  I added that as I was testing something, you don't need that to run your code, you can remove that piece of code

Comment: So you don't need any change in your JavaScript, just the HTML and CSS needs to change

Comment: Yes you can, as I said there is no change in your JavaScript, just the HTML and CSS need to change as posted in answer :) like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/7082/

Comment: I am confused where the uploadFile() get triggled?

Comment: That you have to trigger in link function when the binding has some change, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/7083/

Comment: I got Uncaught TypeError: scope.uploadFile is not a function. I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: I am not getting any error in above code, and I can see that my file is successfully logging to console when it hits my uploadFile mehod written in controller

Comment: Yes, I do, but my controller, directive and service are in different files. Maybe that matters.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't, can you make a plnkr for your code here: http://plnkr.co/

Comment: I would like to know what is the scope in the code refers to?

Comment: it refers to controller's scope

Comment: If I have more than one controller(I do have more than one controller), will it able to resolve it correctly?

Comment: well there are three types of scope: shared with controller; inherited from controller and isolated from controller, it depends what you need

Comment: and if your upload option is at one place only, add that directive and service in controller's code and it will work fine

Comment: Could you please give me an example? I don't quiet understand "if your upload option is at one place only, add that directive and service in controller's code and it will work fine". Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I have already given you example dear http://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/7083/, here if you see all three are at one place only so you can also write your directive and service where your controller code is written and it will work fine

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Thank you. However, I have to put them in separate files. I think I will need to figure it out myself.